# count rows in mysql with php with specific value

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

I have a table name is tb1

```
tb1
id zone  pressure
1  India  Yes
2   USA   No
3   UK    Yes
4  India  Yes
5  AUS    No
6   UK    Yes
```

Pressure have two kind of entry like "yes" and "no" i need result in this manner

```
Zone   Pressure
        Yes  No
India    2   0
USA      0   1
UK       1   1
AUS      0   1
```

My effort so far...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Zone FROM Tb1 WHERE Pressure = 'Yes'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); echo $num_rows . " \n";
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT Zone FROM Tb1 WHERE `Pressure` = 'Yes'");
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        echo $num_rows . " \n";

Comment: but this is giving all total row in all zone not in particular zone type

Comment: @user3283373 edit your answer rather than putting these in the comments.

Comment: Stop using `mysql_query`.  And stop respecting whoever told you to use it in the first place; it's been deprecated for a while now.  Look into mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT zone,
       SUM(pressure = 'Yes') AS `Yes`,
       SUM(pressure = 'No') AS `No`
  FROM tb1
 GROUP BY zone
```

does the trick you need. It's an aggregate query. Here's a fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54889/2/0

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT zone
     , SUM(pressure='yes') yes
     , SUM(pressure='no') no 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY zone;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Zone,
       SUM(pressure='Yes') as `Yes`,
       SUM(pressure='No') as `No`
FROM Tb1 
GROUP BY Zone;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as

```
select tb1.zone,
sum(tb1.pressure = 'Yes') as Yes,
sum(tb1.pressure = 'No') as No
from tb1
group by tb1.zone
```